# DXA Redirect pages

Tags: dxa

Looking at the [online docs](http://docs.sdl.com/LiveContent/web/pub.xql?action=home&pub=SDL%20DXA-v2&lang=en-US#docid=GUID-2BCCA844-F1E5-4B1B-870C-722D7DB57D69&addHistory=true&query=redirect&scope=&tid=8d5449fc-6041-43eb-aa1c-9aee64a0133a&filename=GUID-2BCCA844-F1E5-4B1B-870C-722D7DB57D69.xml&resource=&inner_id=&toc=false&eventType=lcContent.loadDocGUID-2BCCA844-F1E5-4B1B-870C-722D7DB57D69&url=/LiveContent/web/search.xql%3Fc%3Dt%26pub%3DSDL%20DXA-v2%26lang%3Den-US%26action%3Dsearch%26query%3Dredirect&sid=lcSearch.runSearch1449663584458&currentQuery=redirect&currentScope=) for DXA, I see it comes with Redirect Pages. 
But is there anything for managing 301 redirect en masse?

I've done this before with a key/value schema publishing a file that can be used by the IIS UrlRewrite module.

Just wondering if something like this was already in DXA (as a module perhaps)?

Comment: I don't think there is a module that exists within the OOTB framework apart from Page level redirects which you have provided above already. I am equally curious to see if it exists :)

Comment: Not that I know of. Maybe someone built it and didn't share it :)

Comment: I'm curious if you'd make a separate module or somehow "extend" the existing Redirect Page. Would the editor be able to check a "return 301" in page or Structure Group metadata and then publish _something_?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The features of DXA are chosen following the rule that we only build that, whichwe know/expect every customer will want/need and cand find a common implementation of.

Stuff which is custom for every other customer, typically does not fall under that rule, neither does stuff that only some customers need and others don't care about that much.

Keep in mind we needed something a rule to determine what to buld/deliver first to make it a valuable acceleration framework. It is simply mpossible to deliver all the functionality that we can think of in a reasonable time.

That all being said, we indeed do not have anything for managing 301 redirect en masse. Partially because we didn't find a common implementation of that and partially because it doesn't really belong to the web application, but more to the application server.

So this leaves you with a very nice opportunity to create a module for DXA that and submit a pull request on our [modules repository](https://github.com/sdl/dxa-modules) ;o)

Comment: No problem - the essence of the question was just to find out if there was one before we started to implement something.

Answer (score 3):

I think for mass redirects, the overhead of the MVC application (DXA) would introduce a performance overhead.

Redirecting at the IIS level would be preferable, with the URLRewrite module

Comment: Indeed - but the definition and publish of 301 redirects themselves could still be within Tridion.

Comment: I vote for the IIS URL Rewrite module.